# Count rows of data on form by counting hidden fields jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form that allow users to dynamically add rows.i need to know how many rows the form have before its posted.i have created a hidden field that i intend to count then add the amount hidden fileds(rows) to the hidden field value.can anyone help i am not getting that part correct.
the form

```
 <tbody>
  <tr>
<td><input type="text" name="Item_No1" id="Item_No1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Item_Desc1" id="Item_Desc1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Qty1" id="Qty1"></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name ="hidden1"id="inputfield1"></td> 
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

the jquery that creates new rows but it is not counting rows and adding it to the hidden field

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function ($) {         
          $("button").on("click", function () {            
              addTableRow($("table"));        
              return false;
          });
          function addTableRow(table) {
              var $tr = $(table).find("tbody tr:last").clone();      
              $tr.find("input,select").val('').attr("name", function () {                 
                  var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);                
                  return parts[1] + ++parts[2];              
              }).attr("id", function () {
                  var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                  return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
              });           
              $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);
          };
          //counts hidden field
          var con = $("hidden1").length;
          //passes amount of hidden fields as value to hidden field         
          var hid = ($("input#hidden1").val("con"));
          $("#inputfield1").append(hid);
      });
        </script>
```

Comment: why not have a variable that is incremented every time the addrow function is called? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZXDt/)

Comment: was going that route but just counldnt get it done.found some  similar examples online that used hidden field count which also makes  passing it to server easier.

Comment: did you look at the fiddle i posted? its pretty easy and i think storing a working var in a hidden input might not be the best way to go

Comment: thanks it works...the conundrum is posting that value with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Give one of the field a class name. Then:

`$('.myClass').length` will be the number of rows.

Comment: var con = $('.count').length works but it is not moving from 1.after i add multiple rows, also will this add the returned value to the field var hid = ($("input#hidden1").val("con"));
          $("#inputfield1").append(hid);

Answer (score 0):

```
      var con = $("hidden1").length;
```

This is not correct, change it to:

```
      var con = $("input[type=hidden]").length;
```

Comment: this also returns 1.when more than 1 rows are added.